# How to get non_field_errors on template when using FormView and ModelForm

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm using FormView with ModelForm to process a registration form. In case of duplication of email i'm raising ValidationError. But this error message is not available on registration template as non_field_errors.

When i tried to find what is the form.errors in form_invalid method in RegistrationView, its showing the expected the errors, but somehow its not getting passed to template.

Comment: You'll need to show the template. For a start, it's `non_field_errors`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : i've edited that. I found that FormView is not supposed to work with ModelForm `https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L181-190`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, We will have to make sure if its a non_field_error or a field error.

**Where have you raise `ValidationError` in the ModelForm you have defined ?**

1. If its raised in `def clean()` of the Form, then it would be **present in non_field_errors** and can be accessed via `form.non_field_errors` in template
2. If it is raised in `def clean_<field_name>()` then, **it would be a field error** and can be accessed via `form.errors` or `form.<field_name>.error`  in template

*Please decide for yourself where do you want to raise it.*

**Note**: ModelForm can work with with FormView. But Ideally, there are CreateView and UpdateView for that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
{% if my_form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
    <ul>
        {% for error in my_form.non_field_errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```